# Why is my COUNTA formula counting too high?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I know a similar but different question has been asked, but I don’t know how to use query or where to learn, so I figured I’d ask…

I’d like to use this formula:
`=COUNTA(FILTER($L:$L,OFFSET($L:$L,0,1)="Draw",$L:$L=$E2))`
L:L is a range of names, which it should test against E2:E, a range of unique names. I also need to ensure that the cell in the column to the right of each instance of the name in E2:E has a specific word in it (“Draw”). I tried using AND, but this just sets everything to 1, even when one of them has 3 draws. There are no losses, so the loss column should show up as all 0s, but it is instead 1s. The infuriating thing about this is that the draw column is all right for some reason. Picture below. For reference, Losses(as well as draws and wins)are the end goal.

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MBk9T.jpg)

Comment: Why are you using `COUNTA` instead of `COUNTIFS`?

Comment: I thought COUNTIFS was a conditional form of COUNT. Is it a conditional form of COUNTA?

Comment: `COUNTIFS` and `COUNTIF` are conditional forms of `COUNTA`.  `COUNT` is *also* a conditional form of `COUNTA`, where the condition is "contains a numerical value" (i.e. `COUNTA` on "5" "HELLO" "12" "GOODBYE" "20" will return a result of `5`, but `COUNT` will only return `3`, because it will ignore the "HELLO" and "GOODBYE" cells)

Answer (score 0):

`COUNT` is meant for counting numeric values, `COUNTA` for non empty cells. `COUNTIF` or `COUNTIFS` would probably be your best choice. Try with:

```
=COUNTIFS($L:$L,E2,OFFSET($L:$L,0,1),"Draw")
```